# Zend_Amf Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.BadVersion

Tags: php, apache-flex, amf

I am currently building a Flex application with a PHP backend. The flex application should talk to the backend using Zend_AMF.

I have implemented the Zend_AMF endpoint as a controller, so it is accessible via http://localhost/myapp/amf.

I am trying to test the service using a service browser called ZamfBrowser.

When connecting, I get this error:

```
There was an error loading the server's info.  Error: (mx.rpc.events::FaultEvent)#0
  bubbles = false
  cancelable = true
  currentTarget = (mx.rpc.remoting.mxml::RemoteObject)#1
    channelSet = (mx.messaging::ChannelSet)#2
      authenticated = false
      channelIds = (Array)#3
        [0] (null)
      channels = (Array)#4
        [0] (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#5
          authenticated = false
          channelSets = (Array)#6
          connected = false
          connectTimeout = -1
          enableSmallMessages = true
          endpoint = "http://localhost/myapp/amf"
          failoverURIs = (Array)#7
          id = (null)
          mpiEnabled = false
          netConnection = (flash.net::NetConnection)#8
            client = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#5
            connected = false
            maxPeerConnections = 8
            objectEncoding = 3
            proxyType = "none"
            uri = "http://localhost/myapp/amf"
          piggybackingEnabled = false
          polling = false
          pollingEnabled = true
          pollingInterval = 3000
          protocol = "http"
          reconnecting = false
          recordMessageSizes = false
          recordMessageTimes = false
          requestTimeout = -1
          uri = "http://localhost/myapp/amf"
          url = "http://localhost/myapp/amf"
          useSmallMessages = false
      clustered = false
      connected = false
      currentChannel = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#5
      heartbeatInterval = 0
      initialDestinationId = (null)
      messageAgents = (Array)#9
        [0] (mx.rpc::AsyncRequest)#10
          authenticated = false
          autoConnect = true
          channelSet = (mx.messaging::ChannelSet)#2
          clientId = (null)
          connected = false
          defaultHeaders = (null)
          destination = "AMF"
          id = "D8377B12-6625-6224-9ADD-26CFA97594DC"
          priority = -1
          reconnectAttempts = 0
          reconnectInterval = 0
          requestTimeout = -1
          subtopic = ""
    concurrency = "multiple"
    convertParametersHandler = (null)
    convertResultHandler = (null)
    destination = "AMF"
    endpoint = "http://localhost/myapp/amf"
    getServices = (mx.rpc.remoting.mxml::Operation)#11
      argumentNames = (Array)#12
      arguments = (Object)#13
      concurrency = "multiple"
      lastResult = (null)
      makeObjectsBindable = true
      name = "getServices"
      operationManager = (null)
      properties = (null)
      resultElementType = (null)
      resultType = (null)
      service = (mx.rpc.remoting.mxml::RemoteObject)#1
      showBusyCursor = true
    makeObjectsBindable = true
    managers = (null)
    operations = (Object)#14
      getServices = (mx.rpc.remoting.mxml::Operation)#11
    requestTimeout = -1
    showBusyCursor = true
    source = "ZendAmfServiceBrowser"
  eventPhase = 2
  fault = (mx.rpc::Fault)#15
    content = (Object)#16
    errorID = 0
    faultCode = "Client.Error.MessageSend"
    faultDetail = "Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.BadVersion: : url: 'http://localhost/myapp/amf'"
    faultString = "Send failed"
    message = "faultCode:Client.Error.MessageSend faultString:'Send failed' faultDetail:'Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.BadVersion: : url: 'http://localhost/myapp/amf''"
    name = "Error"
    rootCause = (mx.messaging.events::ChannelFaultEvent)#17
      bubbles = false
      cancelable = false
      channel = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#5
      channelId = (null)
      connected = false
      currentTarget = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#5
      eventPhase = 2
      faultCode = "Channel.Connect.Failed"
      faultDetail = "NetConnection.Call.BadVersion: : url: 'http://localhost/myapp/amf'"
      faultString = "error"
      reconnecting = false
      rejected = false
      rootCause = (Object)#18
        code = "NetConnection.Call.BadVersion"
        description = ""
        details = ""
        level = "error"
      target = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#5
      type = "channelFault"
  headers = (null)
  message = (mx.messaging.messages::ErrorMessage)#19
    body = (Object)#16
    clientId = (null)
    correlationId = "60935430-9E15-0B99-3D33-26CFA976D93E"
    destination = ""
    extendedData = (null)
    faultCode = "Client.Error.MessageSend"
    faultDetail = "Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.BadVersion: : url: 'http://localhost/myapp/amf'"
    faultString = "Send failed"
    headers = (Object)#20
    messageId = "BDB90F14-D0D5-FAFF-6A6C-26CFA9DE9C02"
    rootCause = (mx.messaging.events::ChannelFaultEvent)#17
    timestamp = 0
    timeToLive = 0
  messageId = "BDB90F14-D0D5-FAFF-6A6C-26CFA9DE9C02"
  statusCode = 0
  target = (mx.rpc.remoting.mxml::RemoteObject)#1
  token = (mx.rpc::AsyncToken)#21
    message = (mx.messaging.messages::RemotingMessage)#22
      body = (Array)#23
      clientId = (null)
      destination = ""
      headers = (Object)#24
      messageId = "60935430-9E15-0B99-3D33-26CFA976D93E"
      operation = "getServices"
      source = "ZendAmfServiceBrowser"
      timestamp = 0
      timeToLive = 0
    responders = (null)
    result = (null)
  type = "fault"
```

I have tried googling for a solution, but can't seem to find any reasons that will cause that error. I have checked the php code with display_errors turned on, and there were no errors.

If I visit my endpoint in a browser, I get a prompt to save a application/amf file. Opening it showed Zend Amf Endpoint.

I am at lost as to what else can be causing the error.

Any ideas appreciated.

Edit: Some php code. I am simply implementing Zend_AMF in a controller

```
class AmfController extends BaseController{

   public function __construct(){
      $server = new Zend_Amf_Server();
      $server->setProduction(false);

      $server->setClass( 'ZendAmfServiceBrowser' );
      ZendAmfServiceBrowser::setAmfServer($server);
      echo($server->handle());
   }

}
```

Edit: Charles. I tried using Charles with the windows proxy turned on, but it does not seem to capture anything from ZamfBrowser.

If I visit the endpoint from a rowser, I get prompted to save a file (the amf message). Here is the charles output:

```
GET /myapp/www/amf HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Cookie: SESSb4604b0fcf7c7bac0da8afac2a88b017=JxMrgUUT0rl6RnLAR3emeX9gaI_Dikm3DJ4oF2TW2vQ
```

The Raw output (Which could not be decoded as AMF):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 14 Jul 2011 06:15:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_fcgid/2.3.6
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/x-amf

<p>Zend Amf Endpoint</p>
```

Comment: Do you have a Service Browser you can test with?

Comment: I am using ZamfBrowser to test my endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Zend_AMF users, `NetConnection.Call.BadVersion` almost always means that you're not sending back AMF. Sometimes it's because you have an errant `echo` before you output the AMF, sometimes it's because you're getting an error in your PHP code and it's spitting out the backtrace, or sometimes it's not sending anything back at all. In cases like these I'll use a packet sniffer like [Packetyzer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/packetyzer/) on Windows or [Cocoa Packet Analyzer](http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/) on Mac OS X to see what is being sent back. You can also use PHP output buffers to collect all output and save it to a file for examination instead of using a packet sniffer.

Comment: Turns out it was parts of the zend framework throwing up require_once errors. I am using a custom loader and am converting the full class name into a path to include. A temp fix was to remove all the "require_once" statements from all the zend files. Some how those errors were surpressed from output, so I had to turn on php logging to files and check the logs each time a method was called.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, I'm not sure, but I wonder about the object encoding of your net connection?

```
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.ObjectEncoding;

    // Set AMF version for AMFPHP
    var netConnection:NetConnection;
    netConnection.objectEncoding = ObjectEncoding.AMF0; // instead of AMF3
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jason :) I am currently not even up to the point where I am building the flex side of the application. I am just using a service browser (ZAmfBrowser) to execute methods remotely. I was able to get a demo endpoint provided by the author to work, but installing that endpoint on my own webserver or testing zend_amf from my framework does not work.

Comment: Can you post any PHP code?  It's probably the MIME-type of the response, which could also indicate errors in the PHP code or maybe hooks are not enabled correctly to load Zend classes.  I wonder if a proxy debugger like Charles might provide any additional information?

Comment: From the snippet, you define $server, but then pass $this->_amfServer to setAmfServer.  Maybe that's the private variable and $server is a public getter / setter?

Comment: Sorry. Initially I had getter /setters. I then simplified everything to try and get it to work. I have updated the php code.

Comment: I've posted some output from Charles. I wish there was a way I could capture output from ZamfBrowser through charles.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about ZendAMF, but in BlazeDS you get the `BadVersion` error typically when you try to mix'n'match `http` and `https`.